# rails syntax error when add column to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a music app with rails where I encountered error, just wondering does anyone know what it means?

when I did

```
rails g migration add_quantity_to_line_items quantity:integer, default: 1
rails db:migrate
```

which threw back

```
rails aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/Code/Ruby/musicapp/db/migrate/20190605091214_add_quantity_to_line_items.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting do or '{' or '('
    add_column :line_items, :default, :string
               ^
/Users/mrswordsmith/Code/Ruby/musicapp/db/migrate/20190605091214_add_quantity_to_line_items.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
    add_column :line_items, :1, :string
```

```
class AddQuantityToLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :line_items, :quantity, :integer,
    add_column :line_items, :default, :string
    add_column :line_items, :1, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of the `/Users/Code/Ruby/musicapp/db/migrate/20190605091214_add_quantity_to_line_items.rb` file ?

Comment: @BTL sure! nps, I've updated it.

Comment: Remove the comma after `:integer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve is this :

```
class AddQuantityToLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :line_items, :quantity, :integer, default: 1
  end
end
```

There are 2 mistakes in your migration script :

- You can not put comma (`,`)
- Default migration generator does not handle default values, You have to  manually update the migration.

So the migration script should only be `rails g migration add_quantity_to_line_items quantity:integer`

Comment: should be `line_items`, not `addresses`